# How to center align <ul><li> which serves as menu?

Tags: css

I tried to wrap it in div, I tried bunch of different code, but I cannot make it.
I will appreciate any help.

I don't know where am I making mistake.

```css
.menu2 {
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu2 li {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 1px;
}
.menu2 > li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
.menu2:hover > li a {
  opacity: .5;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
.menu2 > li:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #D2383C;
  border-color: #D2383C;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu2">
<li><a href="">2014</a></li>
<li><a href="">2013</a></li>
<li><a href="">2012</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: first of all, those are not "commands". Then, it's rare to use `justify-content` and `align-items`

Answer (score 2):

`float: left` will left-align your list items. You can achieve a similar effect to floating by using `display: inline-block` instead. Then put `text-align: center` on your `.menu2` rather than `align-items`.

```css
.menu2 {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu2 li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 1px;
}
.menu2 > li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
.menu2:hover > li a {
  opacity: .5;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
.menu2 > li:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #D2383C;
  border-color: #D2383C;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu2">
<li><a href="">2014</a></li>
<li><a href="">2013</a></li>
<li><a href="">2012</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that a caveat of `display: inline-block` is that whitespace between the items will produce visual space between the menu items (notice the wider gap between the items in my code snippet versus the OP's). There are several possible solutions to this:

(1) Placing all `li`s on the same line with no whitespace between `</li><li>` (but this doesn't look too good in the source

```
<ul class="menu2">
<li><a href="">2014</a></li><li><a href="">2013</a></li><li><a href="">2012</a></li>
</ul>
```

(2) Achieving the equivalent effect by putting the whitespace in a comment (which also looks weird), e.g.

```
<ul class="menu2">
<li><a href="">2014</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="">2013</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="">2012</a></li>
</ul>
```

(3) Specifying `font-size: 0;` on `.menu2` and overriding the `font-size` on the `.menu2 li`.

Comment: quite close to align center, but still you need to reset `<ul>`'s padding to perfectly align.

Comment: Good point, I'll add that.

Answer (score 2):

You only have to style the `<ul>` tag with `margin: auto` and `display: table`. Note that `display: table` may not work well in old IE browsers (See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)).

```css
.menu2 {
  list-style: none;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  padding-left: 0; /* reset the left padding of <ul> */
}
.menu2 li {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 1px;
  
}
.menu2 > li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
.menu2:hover > li a {
  opacity: .5;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
.menu2 > li:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #D2383C;
  border-color: #D2383C;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu2">
<li><a href="">2014</a></li>
<li><a href="">2013</a></li>
<li><a href="">2012</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

For modern websites, you can take the advantage of `<nav>` HTML tags to make menus. Example is available [here](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/).

Comment: I think this answer is better than mine, unless you're worried IE < 8.